# Why is the following flexbox sizing weirdly (in Chrome 40)?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have three boxes in my flex container. All are expected to be no larger than their contents. Header and footer content is expected to be pretty small, but main content might overflow -- in which case it should start scrolling.

I do not want to hardcode size of header or footer anywhere.

I used `flex: 0 1 auto` on all, and `overflow: auto` on the middle one.
Here is the full example (click main section to add more list items):

```js
$(function() {
    $('.main').click(function() {
        $('ol').append('<li>Item</li>');
    });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 400px;
  width: 247px;
  color: white;
}

header {
  background-color: #1abc9c;    
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.main {
  background-color: #3498db;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer {
  background-color: #34495e;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

/* ignore this, just making things nicer */
body { font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'OpenSans', sans-serif; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="main">
    <ol>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
  </div>  
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</div>
```

This mostly works, but once `.main` starts overflowing, Chrome starts reducing sizing of header and footer by ~ one pixel per item, resulting in this:

[image: Result in Chrome, header and footer are really narrow]

This doesn't happen in Firefox.

Is this a Chrome or Firefox bug? What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to "what's the right way": header and footer should have `flex: 0 0 auto` because they shouldn't shrink.

However, it seems to be a bug described at https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#1-minimum-content-sizing-of-flex-items-not-honored -- even `1` shouldn't shrink them beyond the content size. I assume that because it is an open bug, any inconsistencies in behaviour between Chrome and Firefox are to be expected.

**Update:**
Works as expected in Chrome 45. Link above specifies it was fixed in Chrome 44, so it was probably a bug (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=426898).